# Encrypt through Java and Decrypt through SQL Server AES 256

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, java, cryptography

Am trying to insert some value through JAVA Application with AES Algorithm and need to decrypt the data from the SQL Procedure and need to process a data.

Which is the best practice to do so?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your question? While your question does provide a general idea of what you want to achieve, there is no actual problem and hence your question might be closed as **Shopping List Question**. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_.

Comment: actually, need some help in the SQL side where I don't know how to implement it in the SQL procedure and decrypt the content.